# How can I fix the error of "unassigned variable" even tho the variable has been initialized?

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, asynchronous, testing

I have this code :

```dart
void main() {
  RethinkDb r = RethinkDb();
  Connection connection;
  UserService sut;

  setUp(() async {
    connection = await r.connect(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 28015);
    await createDb(r, connection);
    sut = UserService(r, connection); // second line
  });

  test('creates a new user documenet in database', () async {
    final user = User(
      userName: 'test',
      photoUrl: 'url',
      active: true,
      lastSeen: DateTime.now(),
    );
    final userWithId = await sut.connect(user); // first line
    expect(userWithId.id, isNotEmpty);
  });
}
```

I'm having an error on "first line" that says that the `sut` variable must be initialized, but when you look at "second line", you can see that the `sut` is indeed initialized, and the `setUp()` function is called before the `test()`.

Comment: Because you can't create a non-nullable variable without assigning a value to it at creation. please read about null safety in Dart. https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cases where you don't need to explicitly use `late` even with non-nullable variables with no initial value.  For example:

```dart
void main() {
  int x;
  x = 42;
  print(x);
}
```

or:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  int x;
  if (Random().nextBool()) {
    x = 1;
  } else {
    x = 0;
  }
  print(x);
}
```

In those cases, through control flow analysis, the compiler can guarantee that all code paths result in `x` being initialized before it's used.

> but when you look at "second line", you can see that the `sut` is indeed initialized, and the `setUp()` function is called before the `test()`.

The problem is that the semantics of `setUp()` being called before `test()` (or more precisely, that `setUp`'s *callback* is executed before `test`'s *callback*) is the behavior described by the test framework, not by the language.  It's non-trivial for the compiler to determine that the `setUp` callback is *guaranteed* to be executed before the `test` callback.  Determining that would involve performing flow analysis on the implementations of those functions (and of any functions they call, and so on), which could be prohibitively expensive.

That's the whole reason why the `late` keyword exists: to tell the compiler that *you* know more than it does.  Using `late` means that you personally guarantee that the variable will be initialized before it's used.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize
your variable like this if you are planning to assign it later

```
UserService? sut
```

Or

```
late UserService sut
```